# Starting cassandra server with custom configuration file

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I was wondering whether it's possible to pipe the configuration file for Cassandra directly from the command instead of picking up the default file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can invoke Cassandra with the `-d` flag.  That flag will allow you to specify `cassandra.config=directory`, if you need to specify one on-the-fly.  Cassandra will then look for the `cassandra.yaml` file in *that* directory, instead of the default.

For other options on the `cassandra` utility, [check the DataStax docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCUtility_t.html).

Comment: In addition to the answer - if you want to specify file, instead of directory, you need to use file URI, e.g. `-D cassandra.config=file:///cassandra.yaml`