# Changing data file directories Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to change the Cassandra data, commit log and saved caches directories by defining a custom shell script for CASANDRA_INCLUDE. I'm modifying the properties in the script as follows :

```
***
data_file_directories = "/usr/pic1/kearanky/cassandra/data"
commitlog_directory = "/usr/pic1/kearanky/cassandra/commitlog"
saved_caches_directory: "/usr/pic1/kearanky/cassandra/saved_caches"
***
```

When I run cassandra I get the error "data_file_directories: command not found". How can I modify the directories correctly?

PS: I don't have write access to cassandra.yaml and can't create the default directories it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

referrer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31295831/3166104) answer Make your own cassandra.yaml with your custom directories and then run cassandra with with **-d** flag and cassandra.config=directory

or set **$CASSANDRA_HOME** variable in your .bashrc and then run cassandra